# Can I use azure notification hub to push to a wpf app

Tags: wpf, azure

I am looking for a way to push notifications to a windows desktop app (a WPF app to be more specific) can I use azure notification hub for it? or are there any other alternatives out there?

Comment: Is this a Windows Store app or a desktop app?

Comment: @Calin, Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to use Azure Notification Hubs for this purpose. The core reason is that Azure Notification Hubs do not work with devices directly, rather it communicates via the Platform Notification Services for each platform (such as [Windows Notification Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx), [Apple Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html), [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)). And none of these services will work with a simple WPF application.

You have to design your own WPF Push Notification service via long polling or Web Sockets connection, and you could probably use Windows Azure Service Bus for that. But how to build such a service, is not subject to a SO question/answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've taken the road of building a wesocket custom implementation

Comment: @Calin  have you built this ? 
any pointers for developing custom implementation ?

Comment: "just" change from WPF to UWP. Thus you will be able to leverage the Windows Notification Service).

Comment: @moghya sorry It passed some time since I worked on this, can't actually rember what I did.