# Azure NotificationHub for desktop app (console application)

Tags: azure, push-notification, windows-services, console-application, azure-notificationhub

I kept on searching but couldn't find anything related to this.
I'm planning to use (if possible) Azure NotificationHub to send push notifications to desktop apps (for example, to a .net framework 4.5+ console application or windows service).

So far, i managed to register a Console App by using the "NotificationHubClient" class, and the "CreateRegistrationIdAsync" method.
However, i can't find anywhere how to create a notification channel to start listening for push notifications on it.

Did anybody tried a similar approach before?

Thank you,
Darksody

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notifications for WinForms / WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026884/notifications-for-winforms-wpf-application)

Comment: Yep, this is what i found as well, i was hoping there is a better way... Because if i have let's say 500.000 devices with my application on them (windows service, winforms, wpf, whatever), that means 500k active connections to your server, and that surely implies multiple servers, balanced, huge architecture behind.... Was hoping for a service like this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-dotnet-standard-send-v2

Just take a look on which version of .net you're working! If you search about it, be careful on which nuget package you're going to add in your project.

There are bunch of samples here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples

Comment: This isn't what i'm looking for. Azure event hub is great, but for microservices or internal service communication. I'm looking for push notifications to send from my server towards the client's desktop applications. So the client must connect to a public endpoint somehow to register.